# Show proofs for inverse of these singular matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices, random-matrices

I tried really hard, but I have no idea how to approach this question. A and B matrix are not invertible, so inverse does not exist. So, how do I go about proving them ? Simply saying they do not have an inverse does not mean they are equal.[image]

Comment: The problem is obviously wrong. The editing is poor. Part (i) is even missing. Just ignore it.

Comment: By the way, it is true *in general* that if $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices, then $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$, so using calculations on examples would be quite silly. If I have proved the theorem “All unicorns are white”, I don't even need to see a unicorn to know it's white.

Comment: The way I interpret the situation, it is true that $\,A^{-1}=B^{-1}\,$ because both inverses are undefined.